# What is time-series database?

Tags: database, time-series, influxdb

What is **time-series** database e.g. **InfluxDB** ?
When/where should I use it? 
Please give me sample of business scenarios for it .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database):

> A time series database (TSDB) is a software system that is optimized
>   for handling time series data, arrays of numbers indexed by time (a
>   datetime or a datetime range). In some fields these time series are
>   called profiles, curves, or traces. A time series of stock prices
>   might be called a price curve. A time series of energy consumption
>   might be called a load profile. A log of temperature values over time
>   might be called a temperature trace.

Also the [InfluxDB has the documentation](https://influxdata.com/get-started/) about it and [Thoughts on Time-series Databases](http://jmoiron.net/blog/thoughts-on-timeseries-databases).

Time series data is often used in scenarios where the data is collected at a fast pace like power plants where one needs to monitor the equipment's stress levels so that we can schedule preventative maintenance for it.

Similarly you can think of when you are observing the stock market where the data is coming at a faster rate and you need to track down the data and the associated time to it.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Tripathi   . So is it DBMS too or its a layer above DBMS ?

Comment: @MohammedThabet:- Technically yes, its a layer above the DBMS. Actually the database is optimized to handle the time series data.

Answer (score 1):

Different vendors have their own definition of time series databases. Here are some interesting read:

[InfluxDB](https://www.influxdata.com/time-series-database/)

[TimescaleDB](https://blog.timescale.com/what-the-heck-is-time-series-data-and-why-do-i-need-a-time-series-database-dcf3b1b18563/)

[MemSQL](https://www.memsql.com/blog/choosing-a-time-series-database/)

[GridDB](https://griddb.net/en/blog/practical-introduction-to-time-series-databases-and-time-series-da)

In short, if the database is optimized for storing time series data then you are looking at a TSDB. This type of database typically have fast ingestion speed, many time series specific functions (such as ts aggregation, ts compression, data retention policy, etc.), the ability to scale and store large set of data, etc.